# sql working with alias from other select

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this select:

```
SELECT 
*,
(SELECT some_value FROM other_table) as a1,
(SELECT some_value FROM other_table2) as a2
FROM some_table;
```

Is there any way to use the values a1, a2 and work with them like this?

```
 SELECT 
 *,
 (SELECT some_value FROM other_table) as a1,
 (SELECT some_value FROM other_table2) as a2,
 a1+a2,
 a1/a2
 FROM some_table;
```

Those subqueries are quite big so it's not good if I have to do this:

```
SELECT 
*,
(SELECT some_value FROM other_table) as a1,
(SELECT some_value FROM other_table2) as a2,
(SELECT some_value FROM other_table)+(SELECT some_value FROM other_table),
SELECT some_value FROM other_table)/(SELECT some_value FROM other_table2)
FROM some_table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WITH` in Oracle. It's very helpful. [Link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)

```
WITH a1 AS (SELECT some_value FROM other_table),
a2 AS (SELECT some_value FROM other_table2)
SELECT *
FROM some_table t
JOIN a1 ON a1.key = t.key
JOIN a2 ON a2.key = t.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT t.*,
       a1.some_value + a2.some_value,
       a1.some_value / a2.some_value 
FROM some_table t
cross join (SELECT some_value FROM other_table) as a1
cross join (SELECT some_value FROM other_table2) as a2
```

Answer (score 0):

A set of scalar variables can be introduced as a one row query which you then join with all the rest query.

```
WITH x AS
( SELECT 
   (SELECT some_value FROM other_table) as a1, 
   (SELECT some_value FROM other_table2) as a2
  FROM dual
)
SELECT t.*, x.a1 + x.a2 , x.a1 * x.a2
FROM some_table t
CROSS JOIN x;
```